# Is there a difference between local and remote notification badge count?

Tags: ios, notifications, push, local, badge

There is a badge count of 0 present in information that is entered in a web page. The information is sent out as a remote notification and as a data stream through sync which creates a local notification.

When I receive the remote notification this is indicated by the fact that the badge key is set to 0.
The [public documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) says this:

> Key: badge, Value type: number; The number to display as the badge of
>   the application icon. If this property is absent, the badge is not
>   changed. To remove the badge, set the value of this property to 0.

When I receive this information through the sync and create a UILocalNotification for it, setting the applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0 means something entirely different.
The [public documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW11) says this:

> The default value is 0, which means "no change.” The application should use this property’s value to increment the current icon badge number, if any.

Also, the semantics differ a bit since you cannot make a property absent the same way you can with a key-value pair in a dictionary.

The question is, how do I compensate for this difference? I don't have any insight on how it works on the web server (backend), I can only see what is actually entered in the UI as far as badge count is concerned. I do notice that when it is received the 0 have different meanings. Should these differences be handled by the backend, or should I handle them in the client?

Is there any reason for these differences?